# Including or omitting the 'to be' verb in a compound subject

Tags: usage

With regard to including or omitting 'am', which sentence is correct, and why?

> I humbly acknowledge and thankful to you.

or

> I humbly acknowledge and am thankful to you.

If correct usage warrants not using 'am' as appropriate, then which of the following sentences is correct?

> I wish and am sure that you'll win the trophy.

or

> I wish and sure that you'll win the trophy.

Comment: Neither is right.  You would say, "I humbly acknowledge and thank you."

Comment: But the use of "humbly acknowledge" in the 21st century marks this as Indian English, and it may be (I don't know) that "am thankful to you" is also standard in Indian English. But certainly it needs the "am", because otherwise the "and" is coordinate a VP and an AP.

Comment: What do VP and AP mean over here? Kindly elucidate...

Comment: You could say the latter, "I humbly acknowledge and am thankful to you", but it is not standard UK English unless written.

Comment: @Colin Fine : I originally answered as you did, but then I changed it.  After reading it, I realised it was all a bit awkward.  One is saying, 'I humbly recognize,' counting on a direct object to appear.  But a direct object doesn't appear.  Only an indirect object does.  Rather than 'you', it says 'to you'.  This is what happens when one tries to blend the active and passive voices together.  Perhaps this is standard fare in India--I don't know--but it's rather a mess for those here.  If it's not wrong, I daresay it very well should be.

Comment: What active and passive voices, @BenjaminHarman? There's no passive here. And I dont find it awkward share an object between coordinates where it is direct in one and indirect in the other. Try googling "praise and give thanks to", and you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: @MadhyaBiharGraminBank: VP = Verb phrase, AP = adjective phrase.

Comment: @ColinFine So you mean to say 'am' is required in both the sentences? That is  **I wish and am sure that you'll win the trophy** and ** I humbly acknowledge and am thankful to you**  should be correct...??

Comment: @Madhya Bihar Gramin Bank : Were you to say it, you would say, "I humbly acknowledge you and am thankful to you."  You would want to put "you" behind "acknowledge."  Otherwise, it looks as if there is no one receiving your acknowledgment.  Applying the object of "am thankful" requires both inferring the prepositional phrase "to you," and simultaneously breaking it up as just a dangling "to" to borrow the "you" for "acknowledge."  The indirect object "to you" doesn't readily come across as the direct object of "acknowledge."

Comment: As my comment above indicates, I don't agree with @BenjaminHarman that there is any need to repeat the "you".

Comment: @colinFine please throw some light on the usage of "am" in both the sentences..!

Comment: @MadhyaBiharGraminBank: coordinators like _and_ and _or_ normally coordinate the same kind of grammatical construct on both sides. They can both be noun phrases ("I like tea and coffee"), both adjective phrases ("The forest was dark and frightening"), both verb phrases ("I picked up my shopping and went home"), both prepositional/ adverbial phrases ("I looked for him in the kitchen and behind the shed"). But it is at least strange if they are of different categories. Your first example coordinates a VP ("acknowledge") and and AP ("thankful to you") ... [continued]

Comment: @MadhyaBiharGraminBank: In your second example, with "am", both are VP's. English also allows you to share an argument of the coordination, as in "I like and respect you". However, Benjamin Harman thinks you cannot do this when "you" is in a different functional relationship in the two coordinands, direct object in the first and indirect in the second; but I disagree, and think that you can do so.

Comment: I think this is not a proofreading question. I think it's a question about whether the 'to be' verb needs to be made explicit when it is part of the second element of a compound subject whose first element contains a verb of a different type (such as _acknowledge_ or _wish_). In short, it's a question about grammar.